# How to plot "Trace Explorer" in Python?

Tags: python, matplotlib, data-visualization

I need to recreate a plot- [Trace explorer](https://www.bupar.net/trace_explorer.html) similar to the one below created in R. I was hoping to use matplotlib, but can't find any examples or references for how to do a Trace Explorer like this. Can anyone point me in the right direction? I do need to be able to do this with Python, though.

[image]

Test or sample data

```
import pandas as pd

data_dict = {"Trace" : [["A-M", "B&M", "B&Q", "BLOG", "BYPAS", "CIM"],
                        ["B&M", "B&Q", "BLOG", "BYPAS"], 
                        ["BLOG", "BYPAS", "CIM"], 
                        ["A-M", "B&M", "B&Q", "BLOG"]],
             "Percentage" : [28.09, 32, 0.98, 18.68]}

data = pd.DataFrame(data_dict)


acronym = {"A-M" : "Alternating Maximization", 
           "B&M" : "Business & Management",
           "B&Q" : "Batch-And-Queue",
           "BLOG" : "Buy Locally Owned Group",
           "BYPAS" : "Bypass",
           "CIM" : "Common Information Model"
           }
```

Comment: @JohanC Added test data

Comment: @JohanC I'm able to create rectangles using `from matplotlib.patches import Rectangle` using reference [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58425392/bar-chart-with-rounded-corners-in-matplotlib) and [here](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/color/named_colors.html#sphx-glr-gallery-color-named-colors-py), but don't know how to arrange them in order and add text inside the rectangle patch. Need few more suggestions from you....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `plt.Rectangle()` to create a colored rectangle and `ax.text` to place texts.

Many variations are possible. Here is some example code to get you started:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data_dict = {"Trace": [["A-M", "B&M", "B&Q", "BLOG", "BYPAS", "CIM"],
                       ["B&M", "B&Q", "BLOG", "BYPAS"],
                       ["BLOG", "BYPAS", "CIM"],
                       ["A-M", "B&M", "B&Q", "BLOG"]],
             "Percentage": [28.09, 32, 0.98, 18.68]}

acronym = {"A-M": "Alternating Maximization",
           "B&M": "Business & Management",
           "B&Q": "Batch-And-Queue",
           "BLOG": "Buy Locally Owned Group",
           "BYPAS": "Bypass",
           "CIM": "Common Information Model"
           }
cmap = plt.cm.get_cmap('rainbow')
color_dict = {acr: cmap((i + 1) / (len(acronym) + 1)) for i, acr in enumerate(acronym)}

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12, 4))
percentage_position = max(len(t) for t in data_dict["Trace"]) + 1.1
for row, (trace, percentage) in enumerate(zip(data_dict["Trace"], data_dict["Percentage"]), start=1):
    for col, acr in enumerate(trace, start=1):
        ax.add_patch(plt.Rectangle((col - 0.5, row - 0.45), 1, 0.9, facecolor=color_dict[acr], edgecolor='black'))
        ax.text(col, row, acr, ha='center', va='center')
    ax.add_patch(plt.Rectangle((percentage_position - 0.5, row - 0.45), 1, 0.9, facecolor='grey', edgecolor='white'))
    ax.text(percentage_position, row, f'{percentage:.2f}%', ha='center', va='center', color='white')

ax.set_xlim(0.5, percentage_position + 0.5)
ax.set_xticks(range(1, int(percentage_position)))
ax.set_ylim(len(data_dict["Trace"]) + 0.45, 0.55) # y-axis is reversed
ax.set_yticks([])
handles = [plt.Rectangle((0, 0), 0, 0, facecolor=color_dict[acr], edgecolor='black', label=acronym[acr])
           for acr in acronym]
ax.legend(handles=handles, bbox_to_anchor=[1.02, 1.02], loc='upper left')
for dir in ['left', 'right', 'top']:
    ax.spines[dir].set_visible(False)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: example trace explorer]

Comment: Thanks for the answer, how to reduce the box size, height of the rectangular boxes?

Comment: Matplotlib scales everything to fit into the figsize.  Reducing the figsize will result in reducing the box heights.  Also when there are more rows, they will be scaled down to fit into the same area.