# How to calculate the Precedence Matrix in Python?

Tags: python, matrix, graph-theory

#### [Precedence diagrams](https://www.bupar.net/precedence.html)

The precedence matrix shows the flows from one activity to another in a rectangular format. A precedence diagram is a two-dimensional matrix showing the flows between activities. It can contain different type values, by adjusting the type argument.

In `r-programming` it can be calculated using `bupar` package.

```
#Example

# Absolute Frequencies
patients %>%
    precedence_matrix(type = "absolute")
```

**Output**

```
## # A tibble: 13 x 3
##    antecedent            consequent                n
##    <fct>                 <fct>                 <int>
##  1 Triage and Assessment End                       2
##  2 Blood test            End                       1
##  3 Start                 Registration            500
##  4 Registration          Triage and Assessment   500
##  5 MRI SCAN              Discuss Results         236
##  6 Triage and Assessment Blood test              237
##  7 Blood test            MRI SCAN                236
##  8 Discuss Results       Check-out               492
##  9 X-Ray                 End                       2
## 10 Check-out             End                     491
## 11 X-Ray                 Discuss Results         259
## 12 Triage and Assessment X-Ray                   261
## 13 Discuss Results       End                       3
```

How to get the precedence matrix using python? Is there any package where a precedence matrix is obtained in python?

Comment: There may be a package I haven't heard of to do this, but you could also use an adjacency matrix where each edge is initialized to 0 and then incremented accordingly to indicate flow.

Comment: Is it `Networkx`?

Comment: "Adjacency matrix" is a broad term referring to a way of representing graphs, but Networkx does have an implementation of an adjacency matrix (i'm unsure if it would work out of the box for your purpose). Precedence diagrams are just a list of edges in a graph and the weight associated with them — you could implement your own.

Comment: I have a simple poc if you would like i can post it as an answer

Comment: Please do add that... @MrR

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `pm4py` `discover_dfg`

Exampleset

```
import pandas as pd
import pm4py

df = pm4py.format_dataframe(pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/pm4py/pm4py-core/release/notebooks/data/running_example.csv', sep=';'), case_id='case_id',activity_key='activity', timestamp_key='timestamp')
```

Converting data to log

```
from pm4py.objects.conversion.log import converter as log_converter
log = log_converter.apply(df)
```

`discover_dfg(log)` will return such a matrix (as a dict) and also a counter maintaining start and end activities.

```
d = pm4py.discover_dfg(log)[0]
```

Data Wrangling

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d, orient='index').reset_index()
df.rename(columns={"index" : "Antecedent,Consequent", 0 : "Count"}, inplace=True)
df['Antecedent'], df['Consequent'] = zip(*df["Antecedent,Consequent"])
```

Final Output

| Antecedent | Consequent | Count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| register request | examine thoroughly | 1 |
| examine thoroughly | check ticket | 2 |
| check ticket | decide | 6 |
| decide | reject request | 3 |
| register request | check ticket | 2 |
| check ticket | examine casually | 2 |
| examine casually | decide | 2 |
| decide | pay compensation | 3 |
| register request | examine casually | 3 |
| examine casually | check ticket | 4 |
| decide | reinitiate request | 3 |
| reinitiate request | examine thoroughly | 1 |
| check ticket | examine thoroughly | 1 |
| examine thoroughly | decide | 1 |
| reinitiate request | check ticket | 1 |
| reinitiate request | examine casually | 1 |

Answer (score 1):

Per OP's request in the comments here is a minimalist proof of concept of a precedence matrix in python using a graph structure.

```
class PrecedenceDiagram():
    def __init__(self, mode = 'relative'):
        # {<str> origin : { <str> destination: <int> frequency, ... } }
        self.graph = dict()
        self.flow_amount = 0
        self.mode = mode
    
    def update(self, origin, destination):
        '''
        increment frequency if origin exists and destination is in
        origin else instantiate origin/destination appropriately
        '''
        if origin in self.graph:
            if destination in self.graph[origin]:
                self.graph[origin][destination] += 1
            else:
                self.graph[origin][destination] = 1
        else:
            self.graph[origin] = dict()
            self.graph[origin][destination] = 1
        self.flow_amount += 1

    def display_precedence(self):
        '''
        display flow frequency
        '''
        print('O','D','f')
        for node, edges in self.graph.items():
            for edge, weight in edges.items():
                if self.mode == 'absolute':
                    print(node, edge, weight)
                elif self.mode == 'relative':
                    print(node, edge, weight/ self.flow_amount)
        print('-'*16)


pm = PrecedenceDiagram(mode='relative')
pm.update('a', 'b')
pm.update('b', 'c')
pm.update('a', 'b')
pm.update('a', 'b')
pm.update('a', 'd')
pm.update('a', 'e')
pm.update('e', 'a')
pm.update('a', 'n')
pm.update('a', 'b')
pm.update('a', 'b')
pm.update('a', 'b')
pm.display_precedence()
pm.mode = 'absolute'
pm.display_precedence()
```

Comment: How can I apply it for a dataframe??