# How to plot bupar Precedence Matrix using Plotly in Python?

Tags: python, plotly, process-mining

I'm trying to plot a [bupar Precedence Matrix](https://www.bupar.net/precedence.html) as below using Plotly.

[image]

So far I tried to plot a scatter plot as below:

```
import plotly.express as px

fig = px.scatter(df, 
                 y="Antecedent", 
                 x="Consequent", 
                 size="Absolute_Frequency", 
                 color="Absolute_Frequency")

fig.update_traces(
    hovertemplate="<br>".join([
        "Antecedent: %{y}",
        "Consequent: %{x}"
    ]),
    name=""
)

fig.update_layout(
    template="plotly_white",
    # Figure title styling
    title= dict(
        text="Precedence Matrix",
        x=0.5,
        y=0.95,
        font=dict(
            family="Rockwell",
            size=20,
            color='#000000'
            )
        ),
    xaxis_title="Consequent",
    yaxis_title="Antecedent",
    font=dict(
        family="Rockwell",
        size=16),
    # Fig height
    height=600, 
    width=1200,
    # Turn off legend
    showlegend=False,
    hoverlabel=dict(
        bgcolor="white",
        font_size=16,
        font_family="Rockwell"
        )
    )

fig.show()
```

How to add the text annotations and create rectangles in **plotly** as per the `bupar Precedence Matrix`?

[image]

[Data Prep](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68805994/14045537)

| Antecedent | Consequent | Absolute_Frequency |
| --- | --- | --- |
| register request | examine thoroughly | 1 |
| examine thoroughly | check ticket | 2 |
| check ticket | decide | 6 |
| decide | reject request | 3 |
| register request | check ticket | 2 |
| check ticket | examine casually | 2 |
| examine casually | decide | 2 |
| decide | pay compensation | 3 |
| register request | examine casually | 3 |
| examine casually | check ticket | 4 |
| decide | reinitiate request | 3 |
| reinitiate request | examine thoroughly | 1 |
| check ticket | examine thoroughly | 1 |
| examine thoroughly | decide | 1 |
| reinitiate request | check ticket | 1 |
| reinitiate request | examine casually | 1 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are close: if you add the argument `text="Absolute_Frequency"` to `px.scatter`, and then update the traces: `fig.update_traces(marker={'symbol': 'square'}, textfont_color='white', textposition='middle center')` this should hopefully give you the desired chart.

Comment: I notice that in the original chart, the markers are all the same size. In the code you included, the markers are sized depending on their absolute frequency, meaning that the text is sometimes larger than the marker. If you want the markers to all be the same size, you can remove the argument `size="Absolute_Frequency"`

```
fig = px.scatter(df, 
                 y="Antecedent", 
                 x="Consequent", 
                 size="Absolute_Frequency", 
                 color="Absolute_Frequency",
                 text="Absolute_Frequency"
                 )

fig.update_traces(
    hovertemplate="<br>".join([
        "Antecedent: %{y}",
        "Consequent: %{x}"
    ]),
    name=""
)

fig.update_layout(
    template="plotly_white",
    # Figure title styling
    title= dict(
        text="Precedence Matrix",
        x=0.5,
        y=0.95,
        font=dict(
            family="Rockwell",
            size=20,
            color='#000000'
            )
        ),
    xaxis_title="Consequent",
    yaxis_title="Antecedent",
    font=dict(
        family="Rockwell",
        size=16),
    # Fig height
    height=600, 
    width=1200,
    # Turn off legend
    showlegend=False,
    hoverlabel=dict(
        bgcolor="white",
        font_size=16,
        font_family="Rockwell"
        )
    )

fig.update_traces(marker={'symbol': 'square'}, textfont_color='white', textposition='middle center')
fig.show()
```

[image]

EDIT: after you remove the argument `size="Absolute_Frequency"`, you can change the marker size and set the font size to get something closer to the image you showed originally.

```
fig = px.scatter(df, 
                 y="Antecedent", 
                 x="Consequent", 
                 # size="Absolute_Frequency", 
                 color="Absolute_Frequency",
                 text="Absolute_Frequency"
                 )

fig.update_traces(
    hovertemplate="<br>".join([
        "Antecedent: %{y}",
        "Consequent: %{x}"
    ]),
    name=""
)

fig.update_layout(
    template="plotly_white",
    # Figure title styling
    title= dict(
        text="Precedence Matrix",
        x=0.5,
        y=0.95,
        font=dict(
            family="Rockwell",
            size=20,
            color='#000000'
            )
        ),
    xaxis_title="Consequent",
    yaxis_title="Antecedent",
    font=dict(
        family="Rockwell",
        size=16),
    # Fig height
    height=600, 
    width=1200,
    # Turn off legend
    showlegend=False,
    hoverlabel=dict(
        bgcolor="white",
        font_size=16,
        font_family="Rockwell"
        )
    )

fig.update_traces(
    marker={'symbol': 'square', 'size': 50}, 
    textfont_color='white', 
    textfont_size=14,
    textposition='middle center'
)
fig.show()
```

[image]

Comment: After removing the  `argument size="Absolute_Frequency"`, the text became too small. How to increase the size of `text`  and `rectangles`?

Comment: Fixed using `marker=dict(size=50,
                              symbol='square')`

Comment: @Pluviophile oh i was just about to post the same thing – glad you figured it out!